# SOAP request by cURL gives back response: There was an error generating the XML document

Tags: curl, wsdl, soap-client

**The XML**

```
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'>
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetProviderTrades xmlns='ZuluTrade.WebServices'>
      <providerId>128391</providerId>
      <currencyIds>
    <string>EURUSD</string>
    <string>USDCAD</string>
      </currencyIds>
      <fromDateStr>1986-08-27T09:00:00</fromDateStr>
      <toDateStr>2014-01-12T09:00:00</toDateStr>
      <validTrades>true</validTrades>
      <lotSize>Standard</lotSize>
      <start>0</start>
      <length>20</length>
      <sortBy>dc</sortBy>
      <sortAscending>false</sortAscending>
    </GetProviderTrades>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>";
```

**The Request function**

```
function http_post ($url, $xml)
{
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$post_string = $xml;

$soap_do = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );   
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $post_string); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_string) )); 
//curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password);

$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
$err = curl_error($soap_do); 

return $result;
}
```

**The call**

```
    $postRequest = http_post('http://www.zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx?op=GetProviderTrades',$xml);
```

**The Full Response**

```
soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. ---> There was an error generating the XML document. ---> <>f__AnonymousType55`2[System.Int32,Z.T[]] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.
```

**The WSDL**
http://www.zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx?WSDL

Haven't found anything wrong with what I'm doing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
      <currencyIds>
<string>EURUSD</string>
<string>USDCAD</string>
  </currencyIds>
```

As per your wsdl, it is ArrayOfInt instead of ArrayOfString.

```
 <s:element name="GetProviderTrades">
   <s:complexType>
   <s:sequence>
   <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="providerId" type="s:int" /> 
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="currencyIds" type="tns:ArrayOfInt" /> 
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="fromDateStr" type="s:string" /> 
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="toDateStr" type="s:string" /> 
   <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="validTrades" type="s:boolean" /> 
   <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="lotSize" type="tns:LotSize" /> 
   <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="start" type="s:int" /> 
   <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="length" type="s:int" /> 
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="sortBy" type="s:string" /> 
   <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sortAscending" type="s:boolean" /> 
   </s:sequence>
   </s:complexType>
 </s:element>
```

And ArrayOfInt is,

```
 <s:complexType name="ArrayOfInt">
 <s:sequence>
     <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="int" type="s:int" /> 
 </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

So your request xml should be like this,

```
<currencyIds>
<int>11</int>
<int>22</int>
  </currencyIds>
```